# Stored Procedures vs Triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

How are STORED PROCEDURES different than TRIGGERS in the MySQL world ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stored procedures are stored as precompilated code (stored routine) and called by the programmer wherever it wants to fire. Stored procedure can return value(s). [About procedures and functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Triggers are named database objects fired automatically when insert, delete, update (or other event) occurred, there can be no explicit invocation. Trigger can not return any data.
[About triggers.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

You can use procedures in trigger's code.

Comment: I believe that I cannot run a trigger on the same table on which an INSERT has just been run ? Am I right ? Also, can I make a procedure run automatically based on an event ?

Comment: You can not CALL trigger, it always executes automatically before or after (defined in trigger), but you can have many triggers that executes on the same event (insert is event too). Each trigger runs on system event or on insert/update/delete event (you need define table for this kind of triggers). You can not make procedure, that runs automatically, but you can have trigger that runs automatically and calls your procedure.

Comment: Well a lot of things are cleared by now, I've reading your links thoroughly. But what do you mean by what you said in the brackets-- "Each trigger runs on system event or on insert/update/delete event (you need define table for this kind of triggers)." Do I need to define a separate table upon which the trigger affects ?

Comment: My mistake, MySQL have not _system_ events. You need define table on which events trigger will affect, while all events on which trigger can be executed belongs to table: insert into defined table, update on defined table, etc. It is impossible create trigger that will work after _any_ table update. You can __not__ create trigger which will be executed after drop table. You can create trigger for each table update event.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is a type of stored procedure, but it runs based off of an event on a table instead of just being a set of instructions to be executed repeatedly.

A trigger is defined to activate when an INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement executes for the associated table.

A stored procedure is a group of Transact-SQL statements compiled into a single execution plan.

Comment: I believe that I cannot run a trigger on the same table on which an INSERT has just been run ? Am I right ? Also, can I make a procedure run automatically based on an event ?