# mysql triggers and stored procedures diff

Tags: mysql

are stored precedures, triggers?

i was asked to write a mysql script file and develop database, on a server that does not support triggers. so my question is, since i can't use triggers, then i can't use stored procedures right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedures vs Triggers in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171432/stored-procedures-vs-triggers-in-mysql)

Comment: Everything you can do in a trigger can be done in a sproc. Everything you can do in a sproc can't be done in a trigger.

Comment: @f00:  I'd have thought it was more the other way around.  Triggers have their triggering events (insert/update/delete) that adds a bit of functionality not available in a stored proc.  Yes, the body of the trigger is essentially a stored procedure, and the trigger in MySQL gets invoked once for each record changed, so in a sense the "scope" of the trigger is limited to that one record.  However I'd still be more inclined to say a trigger can do everything that a stored proc does (it just ordinarily will not make sense to do much if it isn't related to that one record).

Comment: You thought wrong then. i can replicate everything a trigger can do in a sproc but not the other way round !! Try inserting into the same table the trigger is firing on

Answer (score 2):

Triggers involve stored procedures (essentially), but not all stored procedures are triggers.  So if the database is an old version of MySQL (per Ike's answer), both are out.

However it may be a general dictum for your design ("develop database") not to use triggers.  Projects can get into trouble by pushing business logic into triggers on the database.  Yes, sometimes that can solve otherwise intractable problems enforcing complex inter-table dependencies.  But your task may have been to do a more-or-less vanilla design, avoiding triggers in the first iteration.

A stored procedure is not as much a design risk.  It doesn't attempt to "enforce" anything in the business logic, just (hopefully) to comply with it.  And the stored procedure runs when it is called, so it basically acts as a mechanism to store a script in the database and make it simpler to execute than running a script from a client connection.  Stored procedures *might* be useful to designing dataloads and reports, if those are within the scope of your task.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MySQL are you using?

Triggers and stored procedures were both added in 5.0, so if you are using 3.X or 4.X then you can't use triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: Then why do you say that your server does not support triggers?

Comment: to be clear , im new to sql development. now i am using work bench version 5.2, but the told me that the server where im going to execute my sql scripts does not support triggers